# Creating outlook ad-in setup with custom forms in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, outlook-addin

I am trying to create setup for outlook add-in which will have some custom forms opening when setup is in progress.

I tried to find how to do it but I found it for old versions of visual studio.

Any one have any idea how we can do it in visual studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179(v=vs.120).aspx) section in MSDN for Visual Studio 2013.